# Submit custom build output from jenkins to a GitHub Pull request as comment

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

we have a need to set up a jenkins declarative pipeline to manage automated builds/deployments for terraform based project repos in GitHub. Basically what we need here is that for any terraform project repo in GitHub, when a pull request is submitted from a feature branch to some base branch like master, then the single multibranch-pipeline job for that repo runs a build against that feature branch and then for the command where it does a terraform commnand like the below :-

```html
terraform plan -out=tfplan -input=false
```

it then posts that output to the corresponding github PR under the comment section (not as issue comment but just the PR comment), so that the reviewer can review the plan output and approve/reject the PR or add further comments on what needs to be modified in the source code. If its approved then there will be a separate job off that base branch to just do the terraform apply which we have already configured.
So the short of it is that regardless of terraform being the case here all we are looking here is how to add something back to GitHub PR as comment as part of jenkins build. I did install GitHub pull request builder plugin and could post comment on the issues, but not sure how to do that for the actual PR. I would like to have that coded in my declarative pipeline, so very much looking to your help/suggestions on that.

Just not sure how to grab the PR id each time any feature build is run or probably have a way where the build triggers on the branch only when there is a PR from that branch as source branch. Any help or suggestions here will be greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i was able to figure this out by following the below post :- Create comment on pull request. I think i wasn't quite understanding that github treats every PR as an issue while not vice-versa, and so what you could achieve by doing a POST /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number/comments, is exactly what i was looking here.